# AS3 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference when importing external .swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm importing an external swf into my main project by using the fallowing code:

```
var FirstLevelLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var FirstLevelFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Mainlv.swf");


//load level one
startlevelbttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LoadFirstLevel);

function LoadFirstLevel(e:Event){
FirstLevelLoader.load(FirstLevelFile);
addChild(FirstLevelLoader);
}
```

This same type of code works fine when importing other swfs but for Mainlv it doesn't instead it tells me the fallowing error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Mainlv/createPlayer()
at Mainlv()
```

So I suppose the error is in the Mainlv.swf file but I don't see what is wrong and running that file independently produces no errors. Here's the code for the fallowing file.

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;



public class Mainlv extends MovieClip

{


    // player settings      
    private var _moveSpeedMax:Number = 1000;
    private var _rotateSpeedMax:Number = 15;
    private var _decay:Number = .98;
    private var _destinationX:int = 150;
    private var _destinationY:int = 150;

    // player
    private var _player:MovieClip;

    // global
    private var _isActive:Boolean = false;

    private var _dx:Number = 0;
    private var _dy:Number = 0;

    private var _vx:Number = 0;
    private var _vy:Number = 0;

    private var _trueRotation:Number = 0;

    private var allbullets:Array = new Array();

    private var allast:Array = new Array();

    private var score:int=0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function Mainlv() 
    {
        // create player object
        createPlayer();


        // add listeners
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseUpHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, triggerbullet);


    }


    private function triggerbullet(event:Event){
        var mybullet:Bullet= new Bullet();
        stage.addChild(mybullet);
        mybullet.x=_player.x;
        mybullet.y=_player.y;
        mybullet.rotation=_player.rotation;

        allbullets.push(mybullet);


    }

    /**
     * Creates player
     */
    private function createPlayer():void
    {           
        _player = new Player();
        _player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        _player.y = stage.stageHeight / 1.15;
        stage.addChild(_player);
    }

    /**
     * EnterFrame Handlers
     */
    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        updatePosition();
        updateRotation();

        scorebox.text=String(score);

        var t:Number = Math.random();
        if(t>0.98) {
            addasteroid();
        }

        for (var a:int = 0;a<allast.length;a++) {
            for (var b:int = 0;b<allbullets.length;b++) {

                if (allbullets[b].hitTestObject(allast[a])) {
                    //removeChild(allbullet[b]);
                    removeChild(allast[a]);

                    //score     
                    score+=5;

                    if (score==100) {
                        dispatchEvent(new Event("next_level"));
                    }

                }
                if (allast[a].hitTestObject(_player)) {
                    //removeChild(allbullet[b]);
                    trace("hitplayer");
                    endGame();  
                }


            }

            allast[a].y += 3;
        }

    }//function



    /*END GAME*/
    private function endGame() {
        stage.removeChild(_player); 
        dispatchEvent(new Event("END_GAME")); // call End_game function to exit external swf
    }



    /**
     * Calculate Rotation
     */
    private function updateRotation():void
    {
        // calculate rotation
        _dx = _player.x - _destinationX;
        _dy = _player.y - _destinationY;

        // which way to rotate
        var rotateTo:Number = getDegrees(getRadians(_dx, _dy)); 

        // keep rotation positive, between 0 and 360 degrees
        if (rotateTo > _player.rotation + 180) rotateTo -= 360;
        if (rotateTo < _player.rotation - 180) rotateTo += 360;

        // ease rotation
        _trueRotation = (rotateTo - _player.rotation) / _rotateSpeedMax;

        // update rotation
        _player.rotation += _trueRotation;          
    }

    /**
     * Calculate Position
     */
    private function updatePosition():void
    {
        // check if mouse is down
        if (_isActive)
        {
            // update destination
            _destinationX = stage.mouseX;
            _destinationY = stage.mouseY;

            // update velocity
            _vx += (_destinationX - _player.x) / _moveSpeedMax;
            _vy += (_destinationY - _player.y) / _moveSpeedMax;
        }
        else
        {
            // when mouse is not down, update velocity half of normal speed
            _vx += (_destinationX - _player.x) / _moveSpeedMax * .25;
            _vy += (_destinationY - _player.y) / _moveSpeedMax * .25;
        }

        // apply decay (drag)
        _vx *= _decay;
        _vy *= _decay;

        // if close to target, slow down turn speed
        if (getDistance(_dx, _dy) < 50)
        {
            _trueRotation *= .5;
        }           

        // update position
        _player.x += _vx;
        _player.y += _vy;
    }

    /**
     * Mouse DOWN handler
     * @param   e
     */
    private function onMouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        _isActive = true;
    }

    /**
     * Mouse UP handler
     * @param   e
     */
    private function onMouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        _isActive = false;
    }

    /**
     * Get distance
     * @param   delta_x
     * @param   delta_y
     * @return
     */
    public function getDistance(delta_x:Number, delta_y:Number):Number
    {
        return Math.sqrt((delta_x*delta_x)+(delta_y*delta_y));
    }

    /**
     * Get radians
     * @param   delta_x
     * @param   delta_y
     * @return
     */
    public function getRadians(delta_x:Number, delta_y:Number):Number
    {
        var r:Number = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

        if (delta_y < 0)
        {
            r += (2 * Math.PI);
        }
        return r;
    }

    /**
     * Get degrees
     * @param   radians
     * @return
     */
    public function getDegrees(radians:Number):Number
    {
        return Math.floor(radians/(Math.PI/180));
    }


    public function addasteroid() {
        var newast:asteroid = new asteroid();
        newast.x=Math.random()*950;
        newast.y=Math.random()*200;

        addChild(newast);

        allast.push(newast);
    }





} //don't code outside of here
```

}//end

Comment: One of the million exact same questions where the coder uses stage in a constructor and then can't figure out why it throws an error since stage is null in constructor ... millions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from using `stage` into your class without adding the class instance to the parent stage.

So your code should be like this :

```
...

public function Mainlv() {          
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
}

private function init(e:Event){
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseUpHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, triggerbullet);
    createPlayer()
}

...
```

And don't forget to add the Mainlv instance to parent stage :

```
import Mainlv

var m:Mainlv = new Mainlv()

addChild(m)
```

I tested this code and it works fine.